# activeBackgroundColor doesn't work in DrawerItem ReactNavigation v5

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I just need help, activeBackgroundColor doesn't work in DrawerItem in React-navigation v5.. but inactiveBackgroundColor work.. Please help me :(

````
<DrawerItem
            label="Porte Monnaie"

            labelStyle={styles.drawerLabel}
            style={styles.link}
activeBackgroundColor={'red'}
            onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Solde")}
            icon={() => (
              <Image
                style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}
                source={require("../../assets/images/wallet.png")}
              />
            )}
          /> ```
````

Comment: Did you solve this issue?